# GTK+, Glade and gtk_entry double click

Tags: c, gtk, glade, gtkentry

```
Linux, libgtk2.0-cil-dev 2.12.10-2ubuntu4
Glade 3.12.1
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

I have GTK GUI created by means of Glade.
I have entry and button. User enters numbers and press button.
Entry is limited to 4 chars in length and 4 chars in size
Button is connected to signal. Entry is used only for reading:

```
char *eeprom_size_kb;
eeprom_size_kb = (char *) gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(GUI.size_entry_kb));
```

Text in GUI.size_entry_kb is set in Glade as default: "256"
You can double click entry, delete the value and enter, for example, 512 and all is OK.
But next time i click on entry (single click) it turns to garbage, weird symbols like bad encoding. In console at the same time warning appears:

```
Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_cursor_pos: assertion `index >= 0 && index <= layout->length' failed
```

If continue clicking it will end in

```
malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x00000000025b13d0 ***
```

or

```
Segmentation fault
```

I set nothing to that entry and I can't get is it my mistake somewhere or its bug

Comment: What are you doing with the char pointer (eeprom_size_kb) after you get it? If you are modifying it or freeing it, Bad Things™ can happen because the widget manages that memory.

Comment: Yes, I g_freed it... So I should free only pointers that marked in manual for must freeing?

Comment: In this case it was documented to be memory managed by the widget. In general I can't say as I don't use the C API very much.

Comment: Besides reading the manual, this is why compiler warnings exist: if you had compiled with warnings on, your compiler would've told you that you should not be casting away constness on the returned pointer from `get_text()`, which as usual is to indicate to you that you do not take ownership of the string and must not `free()` it.